# Почему вылетает IndexOutOfRangeExeption?

Tags: c#, массивы, консоль

```
double n = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

double doubleSize = Math.Pow(2,n);

int size = (int) doubleSize;

double[,] heightMap = new double[size,size];

Random rnd = new Random();

if (size == 2)
{
    heightMap[0, 0] = rnd.Next(0, 10); // Л-в
    Console.WriteLine(heightMap[0, 0]);

    heightMap[size, 0] = rnd.Next(0, 10); // Л-н
    Console.WriteLine(heightMap[size,0]);

    heightMap[0, size] = rnd.Next(0, 10); // П-в
    Console.WriteLine(heightMap[0, size]);

    heightMap[size, size] = rnd.Next(0, 10); //  П-н
    Console.WriteLine(heightMap[size, size]);

    heightMap[1, 1] = (heightMap[0, 0] + heightMap[size, 0] + heightMap[0, size] + heightMap[size, size]) / 4 + rnd.Next(-4, 4); // Центр
    Console.WriteLine(heightMap[1, 1]);

    heightMap[0, 1] = heightMap[0, 0] + heightMap[1, 1] + heightMap[0, size] + rnd.Next(-1, 1);
    Console.WriteLine(heightMap[0, 1]);

    heightMap[1, 0] = heightMap[0, 0] + heightMap[1, 1] + heightMap[size, 0] + rnd.Next(-1, 1);
    Console.WriteLine(heightMap[1, 0]);

    heightMap[1, size] = heightMap[size, size] + heightMap[1, 1] + heightMap[0, size] + rnd.Next(-1, 1);
    Console.WriteLine(heightMap[1, size]);

    heightMap[size, 1] = heightMap[size, 0] + heightMap[1, 1] + heightMap[size, size] + rnd.Next(-1, 1);
    Console.WriteLine(heightMap[size, 1]);

}
```

вылетает на строке heightMap[size, 0] = rnd.Next(0, 10); // Л-н
если ввести 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`heightMap[size, 0]` означает элемент номер `size` и элемент номер `0`. А до этого вы создали `size` элементов. Значит в этой строке вы пытаетесь получить элемент НЕ последний, а последний +1, а это выход за пределы массива. Т.е. если вы хотите получить получить последний элемент из массива размером `size`, то индекс должен быть `size-1`

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 2):

`heightMap[size, 0]` — неправильно.

Поскольку вы создавали `heightMap` как `new double[size,size]`, валидные индексы по обеим координатам от 0 до `size - 1`.

Соответственно, если вам нужен *последний* индекс, используйте `size - 1`.

Comment: Большое спасибо